# Windows 7 - Show thumbnails for special image formats

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, images

I have several images on my computer some of them are in special image formats like .hdr, .exr, .tif. WIndows shows thumbnails previews for common image formats only, e.g .jpg, .png. How can I get thumbnail previews for the special image formats as well?

[image]

Comment: I am 99% sure that these thumbnails are created by the program which recognizes the file. Think of how some PDFs show a preview, this is because Adobe Reader reads the file and renders a jpeg for Windows to use. If Adobe Reader was not installed then you would not see a preview. What program are you using for these HDR files?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Photoshop is currently set to be the default program to open these files.

Comment: I see, you might need something like this: https://code.google.com/p/sagethumbs/ or this http://mysticcoder.net/mysticthumbs.html or this http://poppeman.se/pictus/

Comment: Something here too: http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/134355-there-way-view-hdr-s-thumbnails-windows-explorer.html

Comment: [This](http://www.howtogeek.com/180643/ask-htg-how-do-i-get-photoshop-thumbnails-back/) link - though it focuses on .psd - might have something for you.

Answer (score 2):

While [SageThumbs](http://www.cherubicsoft.com/en/projects/sagethumbs) or [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnshell/) work well, they are overkill (in terms of disk space, memory, and CPU usage) for *just* showing `.hdr` file thumbnails. For that, you only need one small (56 kB) DLL from Microsoft:

1. Download the (enormous, half-gigabyte) DirectX SDK from Microsoft.
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812
2. Run the installer and install only the Utilities. (This requires the Runtime to be installed, too.)
3. Copy the file `TxView.dll` from the `Utilities\bin\x64` directory in the DX SDK directory into `\Windows\System32\`.

   - *If using 32-bit windows, use the `x32` directory instead.*
4. From the command-line:

   ```
   cd \windows\system32
   regsvr32.exe TxView.dll
   ```

That's it! You can now delete the remaining 142MB of Utilities installed by the SDK. You don't even need to restart Windows Explorer, just F5 in a folder with .hdr files and you'll see thumbnails for them!

Comment: This worked except pressing F5 didn't work. I had to restart my PC. Also, I couldn't find the "DX SDK" directory at first. It's located here - c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK(Month Year)\.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have enough free space on Drive `C:\` (The drive windows is installed).

I have same problem and search very much, and do all things but the reason was not enough space on Windows drive.